# Changing colors of locked cells where conditional formatting rules are being used

Tags: excel, formatting

Cells C3:E6 have a conditional format to change the text to bold and italics when a user overwrites the formula with an integer.  The blue cells have formulas in them that the user did not change and therefore, can change the color manually.  I need to give the user the ability to change the cell color manually to match a monthly color scheme as sections deliver.  Is there a way to allow users to manually change the cell colors when the conditional format rule is applied?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEkzt.png)

Comment: When you are using conditional formatting then you have to mention `bold/Italic` format to that conditional formatting rule.

Comment: No. The CF over-rides the manually set format. However, with a helper column you might modify the CF, and you might set the helper column with a formula that changes value depending upon the criteria that would induce the user to override the CF.

Comment: If the conditional format only sets cell to Bold/Italic, then the user can set other formats, eg Font Colour, or Fill Colour (tested on Excel365)